# Is _meta field editing clear any cache in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to edit `_meta` field in Elasticsearch index mapping many times, but I'm afraid, that this action can lead to performance degrading (for example this action can clear caches). There is no such information in Elasticsearch documentation, so, maybe anyone can help me in this question?